# Bind object properties with string dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a below class

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string Locations { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } 
    public string MaxRecord { get; set; }
    public string PageSize { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    Approx 80 properties
}
```

I have a query string like `"my location_Locations/new york_City/city street_Address/200_MaxRecord/20_PageSize"`

Above string contains the exact property names of the class `SearchModel`. Now I want to do something like below:-

```
SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
string[] Parameters = "my location_Locations/new york_City/city street_Address/200_MaxRecord/20_PageSize".Split('/');
foreach (string item in Parameters)
{
    string[] value=item.Split('_');
    model.value[1] = value[0];
}
```

Comment: I would think this would open up some security concerns.  If you are allowing the (untrusted internet) caller to control which variables get bound.  I could for example, call `/20_City/abc_PageSize/abc_SomePropertyYouDidNotPlanOnExposing/`

Comment: @ppittle: In my case, I do not care if anyone puts any non-existing property in the url, and also i am exposing all properties in the URL, so not an issue for me. But thanx for the concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add following codes to your class

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public object this[string propertyName] 
    {
        get{
           Type myType = typeof(MyClass);                   
           PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
           return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set{
           Type myType = typeof(SearchModel);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            switch (myPropInfo.PropertyType.Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ToInt32(value), null);
                    break;
                case "Int64":
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ToInt64(value), null);
                    break;
                case "Boolean":
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ToBoolean(value), null);
                    break;
                case "DateTime":
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ToDateTime(value), null);
                    break;
                case "String":
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value.ToString(), null);
                    break;
                default:
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
                    break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

and your modified codes

```
SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
string[] Parameters = "my location_Locations/new york_City/city street_Address/200_MaxRecord/20_PageSize".Split('/');
foreach (string item in Parameters)
{
    string[] value= item.Split('_');
    // I changed this line
    model[value[1]] = value[0];
}
```

---

OR

---

```
SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
string[] Parameters = "my location_Locations/new york_City/city street_Address/200_MaxRecord/20_PageSize".Split('/');
foreach (string item in Parameters)
{
    string[] value= item.Split('_');

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty(value[1]);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(value[0], propertyInfo.PropertyType),
}
```

---

For case insensitive:

```
model.GetType().GetProperty(value[1], BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance )
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the property name lookup case insensitive?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: One more thing, can we also check the datatype of the property and make the necessary type conversion?

Comment: Check [THIS EXAMPLE](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/reflection-based-settings-class/)

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: Thanks, I have modified your answer and added checks for proper datatype conversion as described in above link( which you mentioned).

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, thanks, but your edit is rejected by other users, I edited again.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: I'm not sure why they rejected even I made a useful edit. Anyways thanks for editing it again, that must be useful for others.

Comment: it looks a radical change for other users, they dont know its content, and why you edit :)

Comment: Hmm...I made this change so that others can get the complete solution at one place.